# PHP - Llamar una función de un objeto y me sale Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in

Tags: php, array, object

Buenas, me gustaría saber como solucionar este error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home/deluxetests/gestioninternatecnotor/produccio/index.php on line 16

El error me sale cuando hago un `echo` de una array de objetos llamando a una función para que me devuelva el valor del atributo.

Index.php

```
include("llegirDadesCrearMarcades.php");
include("creacioMarcadaSimple.php");

$url='./csv/info.csv';
$_gestioDades = new LlegirDadesCrearMarcades($url);
$_gestioDades->start(); 

$_crearSimples = new CreacioMarcadaSimple();
$_arrMarcades = $_gestioDades->getArrMarcades();
$_crearSimples->transformar($_arrMarcades);
$_arrMarcadesSimples = $_crearSimples->getArrMarcadesSimples();

for($i=0;i<count($_arrMarcadesSimples);$i++){
    echo $_arrMarcadesSimples[$i]->getId();
    echo $_arrMarcadesSimples[$i]->getOf();
    echo $_arrMarcadesSimples[$i]->getDataInicio();
}
```

creacioMarcadaSimple.php

```
include("marcadaSimple.php");

class CreacioMarcadaSimple {
    private $arrMarcadaSimple;

    function __Construct(){  

    }

    function transformar($arrMarcades){
        $i=0;
        do {        
            $this->arrMarcadaSimple[$i] = new MarcadaSimple($i); 
            $this->arrMarcadaSimple[$i]->obtenirDades($arrMarcades[$i]);
            $i++;

        } while ($i<count($arrMarcades));


    }

    function getArrMarcadesSimples(){
            return $this->arrMarcadaSimple;
    }
}
```

marcadaSimple.php

```
<?php

class MarcadaSimple {

    private $id=-1;
    private $of=-1;
    private $dataInicio=""; 

    function __Construct($id){  
        $this->id=$id;  

    }

    function obtenirDades($arrMarcades){
         $this->of = $arrMarcades->getOf();
         $this->dataInicio = $arrMarcades->getDataInicio();
    }

    function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getOf(){
        return $this->of;
    }

    function getDataInicio(){
        return $this->dataInicio;
    }  
}
```

Estos tres ficheros lo que hacen  es coger los valores de una array de objetos y meterlos en otra array.

Comment: Te está fallando cuando llamas la función `getId()`. Revisa las clases en las que usas esa función. A veces es un simple error de ortografía al instanciar la clase, a veces olvido de incluirlas, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he vuelto a revisar y es como decías, el error era por la variable '$i' del 'for' que no tenia puesto el '$'.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas encontrado. Para que no quede la pregunta abierta puedes auto responder dando la solución. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano me pide 2 días por aceptar mi respuesta.

Comment: No importa. En dos días lo pones. Lo importante es que conste que has encontrado la solución.

Comment: Lo siento, pero en este caso, se debe votar para cerrar por No relacionado al ser un fallo tipografico.

Comment: Ok @lois6b  Entonces la cerramos. Saludos.

Comment: No me parece correcto que @Gabriel_bdcp haya publicado una respuesta con la solución después de  que la misma haya sido comentada aquí, mucho menos si haber intervenido previamente.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En el bucle:

> `for($i=0;i<count($_arrMarcadesSimples);$i++)`

el valor $i siempre debe ir con el carácter "$" para indicar que es una variable de PHP

Comment: Esta respuesta aparece después de haber dado con la solución en los comentarios... ¿?

Comment: Tienes razón, contesté demasiado deprisa. Elimino la respuesta, Gracias por el aviso !